# Laravel check if a specific item is present in a table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the following **relationships**

> - a movie has many episodes
> - an user has a watchlist
> - a watchlist has many movies

I get my episodes with eloquent

```
$latestshows = episode::with('movies') ->where('category', 'tvshow')->take(10) ->get();
```

I then display it with

```
@foreach($latestshows as $show)
 @if (Auth::guest())
   <tr>
 @else
   <tr class="{{ Auth::user()-> watchlist **...** ? 'alert-danger' : '' }}">
 @endif
<td><a href="/movies/{{$show->movie->id}}">{{ $show->movie->title }}</a></td>
<td>{{ $show->number }}</td>
<td>{{ $show->created_at }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

How do I check if the logged in used has the show in watchlist? I want to display it with a different color in that case.
Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm just a **beginner** and experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) or [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) (Both native PHP functions) to see which movies are the same, or you can use the ->diff() or ->has() methods from the Collection objects that you are dealing with.

```
<td>
  <a ... {{ Auth::user()->watchlist->movies->find($show->movies->id) ? 'alert-danger' : '' }}>
    {{ $show->movie->title }}
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: It gives Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::{"id":2,"title":" ...

Answer (score 0):

This code gave me the expected result

```
{{ Auth::user()->watchlist->movies->find($show->movies->id) ? 'alert-danger' : '' }}
```

Thank you Oscar, you were my inspiration :P

Comment: Glad I could help :) I have updated my answer, please mark it as accepted if you think it's good enough!